# Design recommendation: Lazy init of objects in an array

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I'll appreciate help with a design question:
I have a singleton instance.

I'm thinking of adding it a memeber: an array of instances (of class x) where x is a class with a constructor that gets some parameters.

I want each cell in the array to have lazy init.

I need each object to be singleton - but is there any reduction or simple way to achieve the same without the pattern the whole array is a member of a singleton already?

What design would you recommend me when:
1) Access to the array's objects needs to be thread safe
2) No need to be type safe

Thanks in advance for any idea\suggestion

Comment: Please elaborate on a couple things... Do you know ahead of time how many total elements will be in the array?  Is there any relationship between the items in the array (can you create the value for element 4 without first creating the value for element 3)?  And do you need to be able to retrieve the value of arbitrary elements or will only ever be looping over this array?  If you are only looping over, then the solution is actually very easy... instead of an array, create a new IEnumerable class and make use of the 'yield' operator

Comment: Fredrik, you're right. Accedently a rule in my gmail put all stackoverflow notifications to my recycle bin.
How do I delete an old post of mine?

Answer (score 1):

If you use .NET 4 you should have a look at the type [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).
More specific with the [`Lazy<T> Constructor (Func<T>, LazyThreadSafetyMode)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792409.aspx).

Comment: That doesn't really help with the scenario of an array whose elements are lazily created.

Comment: @Robert, more specifically an array (or list) of `Lazy<T>` should be used.

Comment: that makes the assumption that he knows how many elements will be in the array and also that the number isn't very high (otherwise there is a penalty of creating all of those Lazy objects during array initialization).  a custom implmentation if IList or IEnumerable is probably the best bet here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement so here is an example of a read only list that lazily creates instances based on the requested index number.

At creation time you specify the number of elements and a delegate that specifies how new instances are created. This delegate will be called as required when elements are accessed via the indexers or the enumerator, e.g.

```
var lazyArray = new LazyArray<Tuple<int, int>>(10,
                       i => new Tuple<int, int>(i, 10 - i));
```

The source of the class is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// A lazy list for a fixed number of items where items are created on demand
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object the list contains</typeparam>
internal class LazyArray<T> : IList<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<int, T> constructor;
    private readonly IList<T> list;

    public LazyArray(int initialNumberOfItems, Func<int, T> constructor)
    {
        if (constructor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("constructor");
        this.constructor = constructor;
        list = new T[initialNumberOfItems];
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (arrayIndex + list.Count > array.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arrayIndex");

        // Remember that we need to access the indexers to create the instance
        // so we can't just copy the list or the array may contain null entries
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            array[i + arrayIndex] = this[i];
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public int Count { get { return list.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }
    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index] ?? (list[index] = constructor(index)); }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    private class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly LazyArray<T> baseList;
        private int index = -1;

        public Enumerator(LazyArray<T> baseList)
        {
            this.baseList = baseList;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return ++index < baseList.Count;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            index = -1;
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return baseList[index]; }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this will not cover every use case, I've had success with System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange() for thread safe lazy object array initialization. You still need to test for an empty array element before the call to CompareExchange, as well as guard against null reads for the array's elements.

```
if (array[i] == null)
{
    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref array[i], new Class(), null);
}
```